# Umbraco bootstrap grid layout not showing correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, umbraco

In Umbraco I have a template for articles. There I want to have the bootstrap grid. I am using the property editor Umbraco.Grid. And I have a layout with 2 columns.

But when I put content in the two columns, they show up under each other instead of side by side.

The genereted code looks like this

```
<div class="umb-grid">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row clearfix">
     <div class="grid-section">
        <div class="col-md-6 column">
           <div >
              <div class="row clearfix">
                 <div class="col-md-12 column">
                    <div >
                       <p><img class="img-fluid" src="/media/1002/jv.png" alt="" data-udi="umb://media/4d802fa47cee47e5aee1e8dc65ffd7ee" /></p>
                       <p><a rel="noopener" href="https://www.jv.dk/esbjerg/EfB-formand-og-soen-investerer-i-slagtehus-og-dyrevelfaerd/artikel/2688513" target="_blank">Læs hele artiklen her</a></p>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="grid-section">
        <div class="col-md-6 column">
           <div >
              <div class="row clearfix">
                 <div class="col-md-12 column">
                    <div >
                       <p><img class="img-fluid" src="/media/1003/esbjerg-ugeavis.png" alt="" data-udi="umb://media/0482c03a9eb24be5aa6b7324ab4b880b" /></p>
                       <p><a rel="noopener" href="https://www.e-pages.dk/ugeavisenesbjerg/383/" target="_blank">Læs hele artiklen her (side 26)</a></p>
                       <p> </p>
                       <p><a rel="noopener" href="/umbraco/~/Content/files/Pressemeddelse 14. februar 2019.pdf" target="_blank">Pressemeddelelse udsendt 14. februar 2019</a></p>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Can anybody tell me what is going wrong here? Am I missing something?

Comment: Something is definitely off, yeah. You have full width columns (col-md-12) inside the 50% width columns (col-md-6). Are you using custom grid editors? Then they might be the culprits (they could be outputting some column styling that they shouldn't).

Comment: But the thing is that I'm not using custom grid. hmmm...

Comment: havent used the grid editor myself, but just looking at the html am suspecting your class "grid-section" has got some styles throwing the "column-md-6" width